# Can someone give a clear-cut idea of $E(X|X<Y)$?

Tags: conditional-expectation, iid

If $X$ and $Y$ be two i.i.d. random variables, then what should $E(X|X<Y)$ essentially look like?

P.S.-Is the denominator equal to $\frac12$?
(the two r.v.'s being iid serving as the motivation behind this.)

Answer (score 10):

The i.i.d requirement creates useful symmetries, so indeed there is a factor of $1/2$ in some formulas.  The following is one attempt to interpret "looks like" in a useful and intuitive fashion.

---

The possibilities for $(X,Y)$ partition into three events: $X\lt Y,$ $X\gt Y,$ and $X=Y.$

Therefore, assuming all expectations exist,

$$\mathbb{E}(X+Y) = \mathbb{E}(X+Y\ |\ X\lt Y) \Pr(X\lt Y) + \mathbb{E}(X+Y\ |\ X\gt Y) \Pr(X\gt Y) \\+  \mathbb{E}(X+Y\ |\ X= Y) \Pr(X= Y).$$

Writing $p_0$ for $\Pr(X=Y)$, the symmetry $X\to Y, Y\to X$ shows that the remaining probability of $1-p_0$ is equally split over the events $X\lt Y$ and $X\gt Y$:

$$\Pr(X\lt Y) = \Pr(Y\lt X) = \Pr(X \gt Y) = \frac{1-p_0}{2}.$$

The same symmetry shows the first two conditional expectations are equal while the third reduces to

$$\mathbb{E}(X+Y\ |\ X= Y) \Pr(X=Y) = 2\mathbb{E}(X | X=Y)p_0.$$

Write

$$\mu_0 = \mathbb{E}(X | X=Y).$$

Solving for the conditional expectation yields

$$\mathbb{E}(X+Y\ |\ X \lt Y) = 2 \frac{\mu - \mu_0p_0}{1-p_0}.$$

Similar (but slightly easier) manipulations show that

$$\mathbb{E}(Y - X \ |\ X \lt Y) = \frac{\mathbb{E}(|Y-X|)}{1-p_0}.$$

Because $X = \frac{1}{2}\left((X+Y) - (Y-X)\right),$

$$\mathbb{E}(X \ |\ X \lt Y) = \frac{\mu - \mu_0p_0 - \mathbb{E}(|Y-X|)/2}{1-p_0}.$$

To begin understanding this, suppose the common distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is *continuous*: this implies $p_0=0$.  The foregoing expression reduces to

$$\mathbb{E}(X \ |\ X \lt Y) = \mu - \mathbb{E}(|Y-X|)/2,$$

(wherein the expected factor of $1/2$ clearly appears).  That is,

> For continuous distributions, the conditional expectation of $X$, given that $X\lt Y$, is less than the unconditional expectation of $X$ by half the expected size of the difference $|Y-X|$.

(This result is intuitively obvious: the amount by which the conditional expectation of $X$ falls below the unconditional expectation must be exactly the amount by which the conditional expectation of $Y$ exceeds the unconditional expectation and those two amounts sum to the expected difference.)

The additional terms $\mu_0$ and $p_0$ can now be understood as corrections for the possibility that $X=Y$.  They are a little harder to obtain intuitively, which is why some care was taken with the foregoing analysis.