# What is the expected value of $X$ given $X<Y$, where $X,Y\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$?

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, conditional-expectation, bivariate

What is $\mathbb{E}[X|X<Y]$ if $X,Y\overset{iid}{\sim}\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$?

I have found that $\mathbb{E}[X|X<Y]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} -\log(\Phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}))x\phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})dx$ but from there couldn't procede.

Comment: You should add the 'self-study' tag and read its wiki.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not at all a homework question. It's a mathematical problem I'm facing to which I have not been able to find any references.

Comment: Is it not self-study?

Comment: It is not self-study, no.

Comment: As for references similar questions have been asked before, like this one: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/326436/119261.

Comment: You may ignore $\mu$ and $\sigma$ (that is, work with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$) because all they do is establish the units in which $X$ and $Y$ are expressed.  Then, by changing variables to $X=(U+V)/\sqrt{2},Y=(U-V)/\sqrt{2}$ (so that $U$ and $V$ are also independent standard Normal variables), the problem reduces to an elementary integral.

Comment: The problem changes due to X and Y not being centered around 0.

Comment: @whuber, when we make the transformation/scaling by ignoring the $\mu$ and $\sigma$ then the inequality is not any more along the nice symmetric line $X-Y<0$. So would the variables U and V still work?

Comment: @Martin You're not ignoring $\mu$ and $\sigma$, but simply recognizing that they play no essential role: they merely determine the units in which the values are expressed.  Thus the symmetry is maintained and the variables $U$ and $V$ work just fine.  You can also show this algebraically. Of course it is crucial that the parameters for the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ be the same!

Comment: @whuber ah of course the two different $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are the same. so in the representation with standard normal distribution the relation becomes something like $X-Y<a$ with *equal weights* for X and Y. (I was imagining a change of the slope as well, which I believe occurs only when the $\sigma$ are different, so different $\mu$ don't matter) .

Comment: @user449277 how did you got to the log in your expression? If I imagine p(X|X<Y) then I think of $\phi(x)(\Phi(x))$ divided by some normalization constant. Then the integral $\int x \phi(x)(\Phi(x))dx$  can be solved by integration by parts $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \phi(x)\Phi(x)dx = \phi(x)\Phi(x)\vert_{-\infty}^{\infty}  - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \phi(x)^2dx $ (more or less, some constants need to be plugged in)

Comment: Thank you all for your input! The answer at [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326436/ex-xy-for-independent-x-y-n0-1) indeed answers my question very elegantly. Nonetheless your inputs were most helpful approaches, as well!

Comment: I would vote to reopen this question and place Whuber's comment in an answer. The problem is different because the duplicate has $\mu=0$. In the duplicate question ( *E[X| X>Y] for independent X, Y ~ N(0,1)* ) the answer is: $$ \frac{E(X-Y|X-Y>0)}{2}$$ in this more general case (*now the line of the inequality is shifted E[X| X>Y+b] for independent X, Y ~ N(0,1)*) the answer should be, I guess, something more like: $$ \frac{E(X-Y|X-Y>a)}{2}$$ and I wonder if the proof/derivation from Ami Tavory works the same, or at least it is not a trivial conversion to make it work on the more general case.

Comment: A useful post [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96671/can-someone-give-a-clear-cut-idea-of-exxy).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to find $E[X_{(1)}]$ given the sample size is 2, where is $X_{(1)}$ the first order statistic. So, for now assume $X \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ we are just shifting the location , later in the end we will add $\mu$ to our answer.(This is just to make the calculations easier). Let $f(x)$ be the pdf of $N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $f_{(1)}(x)$ be the pdf of $X_{(1)}$. Now I hope you know how to show

$f_{(1)}(x) = 2[1-F(x)]f(x)$

so, $E[X_{(1)}] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{2x(1-F(x))f(x)} = 2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{xf(x)} -  2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{xF(x)f(x)} = -  2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{xF(x)f(x)}$

Now use by parts to integrate $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{xF(x)f(x)}$ so,

$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{F(x)f(x)} = F(x)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{xf(x)} - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f(x)\int{xf(x)}} = - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f(x)\int{xf(x)}}$

Now use the result that $\int{xf(x)} = -\sigma^2f(x)$ (you can prove this)

And substitute the result back and solve the integrals to obtain your answer. Your "final" answer should come as $-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{\pi}} + \mu$, this is for accounting the fact that we shifted the location to the origin,so after shifting it back this should be your result

Answer (score 0):

By $\mathbb{E}(X | X < Y)$, you probably mean $\mathbb{E}_{X \sim X | X < Y}(X)$. I prefer this notation since it clearly splits the information in two parts:

1- in subscript, the random variable and the distribution that are used to compute the expectation (in this case, $X$ and $P(X|X < Y)$, resp.);

2 - between parenthesis, the function whose expectation we are computing (in this case, the identity function $f(X) = X$).

Hints to solve the problem:

1 - From the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, you have that $P(X,Y) = P(X)P(Y)$.

2 - Using $P(X,Y)$, derive an expression for the function $f(Y) = P(X < Y)$.

3 - Use $f(Y)$ and the definition of conditional probability to obtain the pdf $P(X | X < Y)$.

4 - Use $P(X | X < Y)$ and the definition of expectation to compute your desired $\mathbb{E}_{X \sim X | X < Y}(X)$.